# Is it possible to convert a png with a complicated gradient to svg without using taking up too much time in 3d programs

Tags: svg, file-conversion

Is it possible to convert a png with a complicated gradient to svg without using taking up too much time in 3d programs. I tried using online programs, but all of the colours wouldn't appear and when they did, the gradient wasn't the same.

This is my original file:

[image: Original picture]

and this is after converting online:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IDA_d4o_UAWWFpQxjMpOATb61bMMsbjb/view?usp=sharing

The only solution is to edit it in a 3d program. The problem is that I'm in a time crunch for this project and I don't have the expertise because I'm a beginner. Im not the on that made the logo.

What should I do?

Comment: Why on earth do you need a 3D Program? There is no 3D there at all. This is fairly easily created in Adobe Illustrator or InkScape.

Comment: Make the shapes using a vector editor like the ones Scott mentioned then add a gradient fill and make it look like the above.

Comment: Why wouldnt you have the vector version?

Comment: What is the original file? which program was used to create? That looks like vector already, can't you ask the author for the original file?.

Comment: @Luciano I can't, they don't have his contact info anymore

Comment: @Scott ill try that

Comment: Let us see, who gets there first!

Comment: Manually edit if possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Auto tracing doesn't work with gradients. You don't need 3D software for this.

Use a vector image editor such as Illustrator or Inkscape (which is free), trace the bitmap just as a solid black graphic, then re-create the gradients by sampling the colours from the original using the Eyedropper tool, and fill the graphics with the gradients.

[image]

If you have more time than me, it might also be better to retype the text instead of tracing it because traced text won't look good close up.